# Unable to Run TestNG program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;    
public class logintest
{
    @Test   
    public void loginT() 
    {   
        System.out.println("Hi Chandra Shekar");
    }
}
```

I installed TestNG in my Eclipse(Helios) and can see TestNG in Windows/Show View/Others/Java.
While running I am facing the following error.. Please help on this..

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching logintest".
org.osgi.framework.Version.compareTo(Lorg/osgi/framework/Version;)I
```

Comment: You might want to consider reformatting your question to ensure everything that is code is displayed as code, to allow users to better help you.

Comment: Looks like you are using a wrong version of something. It might be Java or testNg or eclipse. Try to update all your softwares and retry. If you can update your versions then we can probably find it out.

Comment: The Helios release of Eclipse is from 5 years ago. I would recommend that you go get the current version Mars and see if that helps. As others have suggested you should probably get the latest and greatest of everything while you are at it.

Comment: Thank you Girish, Jeff and star for your suggestions... It is works fine with Luna version..